# Cannot run unit tests on angular-seed

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angular-seed

I followed the instructions on [Running Unit Tests](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed#running-unit-tests) on the Angular Seed Project, but I get the following error:

```
scripts/test.sh: line 9: scripts/../node_modules/karma/bin/karma: 
  No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

The README says the following:

> Requires node.js, Karma (`sudo npm install -g karma`) and a local or remote browser.

But I checked at `scripts/test.sh`:

```
$BASE_DIR/../node_modules/karma/bin/karma start $BASE_DIR/../config/karma.conf.js $*
```

So it looks like `test.sh` is looking for `karma` in the base angular-seed directory.

I did the following:

```
$> cd angular-seed-master
$> npm install karma
$> karma init
   [... followed instructions ...]
$> scripts/test.sh
```

And it worked.

**Note:** It seems the README in Angular Seed Project is outdated as this [Issue in Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/pull/125) from 2 months ago explains. This issue should go away soon.

> **Karma should be loaded from the path - not a relative directory #125**
>
> +1, without this the README setup instructions no longer work.
>
> Alternatively the README could be updated to account for local installation as in angular#132 Though note though that package.json also needs a "version" field which is causes npm to error out on npm install for me when installed locally.